# Folder alias / Symbolic link to return to back folder

Tags: directory, symlink

I need to create a folder "2015" which re-routes to ./ but I don't know what the command is. Not sure if the term is called in this case an alias (or symbolic link).

So I need to make the same "re-route" of the 2015 folder like the 2013 and 2014 folders got the "-> ./"

```
... www-data    2 Jun 19  2013 2013 -> ./
... www-data    2 Jul 24  2013 2014 -> ./
... www-data 4096 Oct 17 13:30 2015
```

For web sub-domains purpose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a symbolic link. Go the directory where they are pointing to and execute:

```
ln -s . 2015
```

should do it. Note the destination shall not exist. If there is currently a directory named `2015` move it before linking.

Comment: Hi! Before I try that, isn't ~ the root destination? Thank you

Comment: I just noticed that it is a relative link in your question. so I edited the answer. `~` is the home directory. `/` is the root node. Also, `.` is a synonym for the current directory.

Comment: It worked, now it looks like this:
`www-data    2 Jun 19  2013 2013 -> ./
www-data    2 Jul 24  2013 2014 -> ./
marc        1 Oct 17 13:58 2015 -> .`

shows ".", not "./" does it make any diference?

Comment: And for later if needed, how can I remove it?

Comment: `rm 2015` is enough. It will remove the link only (no files)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the directory where you want to create the link and run the following command:

```
ln -s ./ 2015
```

The `ln` command creates links, see `man` ln:

```
       -s, --symbolic
              make symbolic links instead of hard links
```